# Calling function from other form textbox doesn't change

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, textbox

I'm trying to call a method from a different form on buttonclick.
If I debug it it does go to the method that I'm trying to call, but as soon as I try to change a textbox inside this function it doesn't work.

Here is my function

```
public void addedtram(string tramno, string rail, string lineno, string sect)
    {
        String tbx = "tbx_sect" + 1 +"L"+ 2;
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.FindControl(tbx) as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            tb.Text = tramno;
            tbx_sect10L1.Text = tramno;
        }
    }
```

I just put this in as a test, because I'm sure that the tbx exists but and with the debug it does say `tb.Text = "1234"`(example) but it doesn't show on my form.

Does anyone have a clue what the problem could be here?

Comment: "from a different form" is certainly significant, very good odds that you just used the wrong form object reference.  A new one instead of the one that the user is looking at.  Add `this.Show();` at the bottom of them method and you'll probably see your changes.

Comment: What is `this.FindControl`? Is that your own method? is this winform?

Comment: that actually worked, only problem is that I never closed the initial form, so when I use this.Show(); I get the form 2 times, tried using this.Refresh(); but that didn't work

Comment: @SriramSakthivel
I found a this.FindControl method for c# somewhere it does the same as the FindControl that you can use in asp

Comment: @TheUnknown there is **no** `FindControl` method in `winforms`, of course unless it's your own method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should expose the contents of the textbox using a property:

```
class Form1 {
  public string txtbox {
    get { return textBox1.Text; }
  }
}
```

Then in Form2 do this:

```
var frm = new Form1();
textBox1.Text = frm1.txtbox;
```

You can make frm a class var of Form2 and call .Show() in the constructor of Form2.